# RavenDB 4.0 - exact parameter of Where clause

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb4

I am trying to play a little bit with `RavenDB 4.0 RC`. I am migrating from `RavenDb 3.0` to the latest version.

The problem I have is extension method `IRavenQueryable<T> IQueryable<T>.Where<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, bool exact)`

What parameter `exact` actually do? From my investigation when I set that to `true` RavenDB is not giving me results from the queries along with Index, where part of the query is string comparison.

I couldn't find any documentation of `RavenDB 4.0` just yet, so maybe anyone came across that and could give me some explanation of what that parameter is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book about RavenDB 4.0 is currently being written, but can be download right now here:
https://github.com/ravendb/book/releases/tag/v4.0.9-preview

In particular, this controls whatever the query will use `exact(State = 'abc')`.
The `exact` behavior controls how RavenDB will treat the query by default. In this case, unlike the use case insensitive behavior, this will generate a case *sensitive* match.

This is applicable only for queries that don't use an index, in which case the definition specified on the index fields take precedence.